Android VoIP client disconnects when changing wireless access point
In the small company I work we have a few company smartphones connected to internet only via WiFi.
If during a call someone walks during and the smartphone changes access point, nothing happens and the call continues normally. But if said thing happens while the smartphone is in standby, the proprietary VoIP client will just disconnect and result offline. It will try to re-go online only when opening the client.
I already contacted the VoIP provider and tried all the discussed solutions, and now I suspect it has to do with how Android handles WiFi and battery saving.
To make sure I missed nothing here I am.
Edit: battery optimizations for the app are disabled
Edit 2: this was the problem, as indicated by Petr Havel

Does your Wifi system (the access points + management) support WiFi Roaming (and may be even 802.11r)? Does the Android devices support WiFi Roaming and 802.11r?

If Android is at the root of the issue, this might better be asked at https://android.stackexchange.com/, if you do not get an answer here.

You don't mention which VoIP SIP client you are using and which PBX you are connecting to.
However, it occurs to me that this problem might occur: The SIP client tries to re-register after changing the network (Wi-Fi), but the PBX (Asterisk?) does not allow more than one registration, so it refuses. Then regularly sent keep-alives no longer occur in the application, so the application can 'sleep' and will not register again. At the same time, this means an inappropriately set interval for repeated registration attempts.

SIP client is NethCTI made by Nethesis, a little company so probably not a well-known one. PBX is hosted. All WiFi Access points connect to a single UniFi controller.

Most likely, the problem will be in the application itself. However, I wonder: Are all battery savers turned off for this app in Android OS?

It's probably built on Linphone.
Won't it be related to this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462155/linphone-cant-receive-incoming-call-on-some-wifi-network-after-some-time
